# word2vec toolkit distance script

Tags: distance, word2vec

I'm using the "distance" script to find similar words over a word2vec that I have built. It contains around 1.6M words and was trained by this command:

```
./word2vec -train processed-text-2016.txt -output vec-cbow-neg.txt -debug 2 -threads 5 -size 300 -window 10 -sample 1e-3 -negative 10 -hs 0 -binary 0 -cbow 1 > w2v-neg.log &
```

My problem is that when I type any word, I get the following:
Enter word or sentence (EXIT to break): rt

Word: rt  Position in vocabulary: 658253

### Word       Cosine distance

```
                                     -0.000451              0.494857
                                        356414              0.477918
                                             9              0.441466
                                            83              0.432876
                                            63              0.431347
                                     -0.020525              0.429472
                                       .047345              0.425791
                                            36              0.423420
                                           242              0.418320
                                         ...                   ...
```

Enter word or sentence (EXIT to break): nd

Word: nd  Position in vocabulary: 336527

### Word       Cosine distance

```
                                             3              0.494377
                                           489              0.492153
                                           632              0.483827
                                      0.002335              0.462591
                                          0693              0.458801
                                        036869              0.452456
                                        036819              0.447690
                                            31              0.443887
                                         ...                   ...
```

Enter word or sentence (EXIT to break): and

Word: and  Position in vocabulary: 1600843

### Word       Cosine distance

```
                                        080852              0.451752
                                            57              0.438413
                                         16577              0.437900
                                             4              0.433538
                                       .005464              0.429279
                                        003131              0.422587
                                         17380              0.420614
                                             9              0.419624
                                          5082              0.419569
                                      0.019322              0.417945
                                       .000435              0.417265
                                        115991              0.414139
                                         ...                   ...
```

Enter word or sentence (EXIT to break): happy

Word: happy  Position in vocabulary: -1
Out of dictionary word!
Enter word or sentence (EXIT to break): man

Word: man  Position in vocabulary: 470143

### Word       Cosine distance

```
                                      0.055039              0.488181
                                          4793              0.455608
                                         90743              0.454786
                                        060493              0.453180
                                            36              0.451387
                                             6              0.450261
                                             4              0.445118
                                           830              0.442580
                                           490              0.439919
                                      0.025327              0.437766
                                      0.005571              0.436606
                                      0.001964              0.436544
                                     -0.012627              0.434358
                                         ...                   ...
```

Enter word or sentence (EXIT to break): women

Word: women  Position in vocabulary: -1
Out of dictionary word!
Enter word or sentence (EXIT to break): queen

Word: queen  Position in vocabulary: -1

If I grep these words from the model file (text file), I find them, so I'm not sure why this is happening or how to overcome this? Is it because of noise in data (I'm degugging this) or in params I used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simply I'm using text format of the model not the binary format...